# Spring Boot, unable to use my UserDetailsService

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I'd like to use my own UserDetailService but loadUserByUsername method seams is never called.
I've tried to configure security in several ways also using a custom AuthenticationProvider but never changed.

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger("SecurityConfig.class");

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        LOG.info("Config http security -------------------------");
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/reader/**").hasAuthority("READER")
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/index")
                .failureUrl("/index?error=true");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
    }
}
```

and

```
@Service
public class CustomUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

    Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger("UserService.class");

    @Autowired
    private ReaderRepository readerRepository;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        LOG.info("Load user by username -------------------");
        Reader r = new Reader();
        r.setUsername(username);
        return readerRepository.findOne(Example.of(r)).orElseThrow(() -> new UsernameNotFoundException("No user found for: " + username));
    }
}
```

From console the filter chain seems like that

```
2021-03-25 17:12:18.642 TRACE 21769 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Trying to match request against DefaultSecurityFilterChain [RequestMatcher=any request, Filters=[org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@50dc49e1, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@184afb78, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@11bfffb3, org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter@62735b13, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@51eb0e84, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter@6a6da47a, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@4f26425b, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@4e50ae56, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@650a1aff, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@1c6e3ff9, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@5773d271, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor@fe8aaeb]] (1/1)
```

while about the reported error

```
2021-03-25 17:12:18.653 TRACE 21769 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] o.s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslationFilter     : Sending AnonymousAuthenticationToken [Principal=anonymousUser, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, SessionId=B40D971684133132E43BA7021EE79C60], Granted Authorities=[ROLE_ANONYMOUS]] to authentication entry point since access is denied

org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access is denied
    at org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased.decide(AffirmativeBased.java:73) ~[spring-security-core-5.4.5.jar:5.4.5]
```

Any idea about what is missing or wrong?

Comment: Yes the SecurityConfig is executed and both configuration methods are called. Also the userDetailsService property is injected as aspected.

Comment: Make sure you add `@EnableWebSecurity` to disable the spring boot default config. Also the `loadByUsername` will only be used when yo login, if you don't login it will never be called.

Comment: Thank you @M.Deinum, I did it even if it's not visible on the attached code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure the password encoder as well:

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger("SecurityConfig.class");

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        LOG.info("Config http security -------------------------");
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/reader/**").hasAuthority("READER")
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/index")
                .failureUrl("/index?error=true");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
            .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
    }
}
```

Declare one in your config somewhere:

```
    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return PasswordEncoderFactories.createDelegatingPasswordEncoder();
    }
```

And where you create your user, also use the encoder to encode the password before storing the password in the database.

Comment: Thank you, but also configuring PasswordEncoder I get the same behaviour. The loadUserByUsername method is not called.

Comment: Not sure what is wrong with the info I see. Maybe cross check with the working application sources from my book at https://github.com/wimdeblauwe/taming-thymeleaf-sources ?

Comment: hi @WimDeblauwe with the above examples if I want to disable formlogin , the loadbyuser() is not calling.. How can we still keep the roles activated even after disable the formlogin.